# purge all packages manually installed via apt-get from the moment you installed the Ubuntu OS

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there a way to `purge` **all** packages installed via `apt-get` from the very moment you installed the Ubuntu OS, up till this very point?

One could call it a a "mega apt-get purge".

The purpose of this operation to clear the system of everything I've installed so far (from `apt`) on top of the Ubuntu OS itself. This would bring me the closer to a **fresh install** of a Ubuntu OS, without any added software (of course, the only thing I'll have left is to clear all non-`apt` software and individual files I've added, but that is of course another issue).

The reason for this operation is because this is done on a VPS machine in which I can't install and uninstall operating systems in the traditional way; I can indeed use the "rebuild" functionality of my hosting provider but I find it a bit annoying to use from personal reasons so I just want to go closest I can to a fresh install without that.

How will you do the desired "mega apt-get purge"? Thanks.

Comment: a  reinstall? it would take me 17 minutes to do so and get the result you want.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've edited to explain why this is not really an option for me, in that particular case...

Comment: @user9303970 still not a problem. I have 10+ VPSes for my business and remount my personal partition in all of them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apt` with some scripting:

```
apt list --manual-installed | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' > ~/list
sudo apt-get purge --simulate `cat ~/list | grep -v Listing`
```

**Please remember - you are trying to perform very dangerous operation.

If unsure please do not remove `--simulate`**.

**On system with 555 manually installed packages `apt-get` writes the following:**

> After this operation, 4 769 MB disk space will be freed.
>   You are about to do something potentially harmful.
>   To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
>   ?]
>   Yes, do as I say!<kbd>Enter</kbd>

then it stops.

**So it is completely bad idea (I have no `cat`, `sudo` commands afterwards).

System boots with kernel panic.

I have snapshot, I'll restore it in 5 seconds.**

---

**Conclusion:** you should use clever manual method - for example determine which services were installed manually (with `apt list --manual-installed`) and running (with `htop`, `netstat`, `systemctl`, whatever) and then purge only their packages.

Comment: Use it to get a list and than loop through that list as it appears in stdout and `purge`? Or you'd use a better way?

Comment: Do not execute the command above if unsure. It may completely break your system.

Answer (score -1):

If you still have all the logfiles from apt in /var/log/apt , you can do: $grep install /var/log/apt/history.log; zgrep install /var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz , this will show all packages that have been installed on the system through apt.

Removing them in one commandline would take some bash scripting.

Hope this helps.